# USB port cannot be detected after program start

Tags: java, usb, javax.comm

When a device is already connected, my program calls `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` from `javax.comm`, and I get the USB port. However, if the program starts and then I connect the USB device, `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` doesn't recognize  it.

What could be wrong?